# Web, scraper, class print only text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#weather.scraper

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

def main():
    """weather scraper"""
    r = urllib.urlopen("https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KPHL/2016/1/1/MonthlyHistory.html?&reqdb.zip=&reqdb.magic=&reqdb.wmo=&MR=1").read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
    tables = soup.find_all("table", class_="responsive airport-history-summary-table")

    scrapedData = {}
    for table in tables:
        print 'Weather Philadelphia'

        for tr in table.find_all("tr"):
            firstTd = tr.find("td")
            if firstTd and firstTd.has_attr("class") and "indent" in firstTd['class']:
                values = {}
                tds = tr.find_all("td")
                maxVal = tds[1].find("span", class_="wx-value")
                avgVal = tds[2].find("span", class_="wx-value")
                minVal = tds[3].find("span", class_="wx-value")
                print maxVal, avgVal, minVal
                if maxVal:
                    values['max'] = maxVal.text
                if avgVal:
                    values['avg'] = avgVal.text
                if minVal:
                    values['min'] = minVal.text
                if len(tds) > 4:
                    sumVal = tds[4].find("span", class_="wx-value")
                    if sumVal:
                        values['sum'] = sumVal.text
                scrapedData[firstTd.text] = values

    print scrapedData


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What it does: this scraper prints me the values of a table on some website.
When I run the code it prints me out the following:

```
Weather Philadelphia
<span class="wx-value">18</span> <span class="wx-value">6</span> <span class="wx-value">-2</span>
    <span class="wx-value">12</span> <span class="wx-value">1</span> <span class="wx-value">-6</span>
    <span class="wx-value">6</span> <span class="wx-value">-3</span> <span class="wx-value">-11</span>
    None None None
    None None None
    None None None
    <span class="wx-value">14</span> <span class="wx-value">-7</span> <span class="wx-value">-21</span>
    <span class="wx-value">35.6</span> <span class="wx-value">2.5</span> <span class="wx-value">0.0</span>
    <span class="wx-value">46</span> <span class="wx-value">8</span> <span class="wx-value">0</span>
    <span class="wx-value">61</span> <span class="wx-value">16</span> <span class="wx-value">0</span>
    <span class="wx-value">79</span> <span class="wx-value">42</span> <span class="wx-value">27</span>
    <span class="wx-value">1038</span> <span class="wx-value">1017</span> <span class="wx-value">993</span>
    {u'Cooling Degree Days (base 65)': {}, u'Gust Wind': {'max': u'79', 'avg': u'42', 'min': u'27'}, u'Min Temperature': {'max': u'6', 'avg': u'-3', 'min': u'-11'}, u'Heating Degree Days (base 65)': {}, u'Dew Point': {'max': u'14', 'avg': u'-7', 'min': u'-21'}, u'Growing Degree Days (base 50)': {}, u'Snowdepth': {'max': u'46', 'avg': u'8', 'min': u'0'}, u'Sea Level Pressure': {'max': u'1038', 'avg': u'1017', 'min': u'993'}, u'Max Temperature': {'max': u'18', 'avg': u'6', 'min': u'-2'}, u'Precipitation': {'max': u'35.6', 'sum': u'66.80', 'avg': u'2.5', 'min': u'0.0'}, u'Wind': {'max': u'61', 'avg': u'16', 'min': u'0'}, u'Mean Temperature': {'max': u'12', 'avg': u'1', 'min': u'-6'}}
```

BUT what I would like is instead of:

```
<span class="wx-value">18</span> <span class="wx-value">6</span> <span class="wx-value">-2</span>
```

is it to print me out the value without the span class

```
18
6
-2
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
justtext = scrapedData.get_text()
```

Check out the documentation! https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. I get the same output as without "justtext = scrapedData.get_text()"

Comment: try .strings() on  <span class="wx-value">18</span> <span class="wx-value">6</span> <span class="wx-value">-2</span>

Comment: how do you mean that. "print scrapedData.strings()"?

Answer (score 0):

You're just trying to print maxVal, avgVal, minVal

Instead, try with `.text`

```
print maxVal.text, avgVal.text, minVal.text
```

Comment: I changed the code to yours "print max.Val.text(), etc.." but I still get the span classes with it

Comment: @malina maxVal.text not as max.Val.text()

Comment: That also does not work. It does work with the last line: `{u'Cooling Degree Days (base 65)`, but not with the span columns